# Firebase Push Notification Working in yarn watch but not Working in yarn build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, push-notification

I'm using firebase push notifications in my project.As I'm using yarn watch in my local the notifications receive without any problem but in the server as it use yarn build it is not working

push-notification.js

```
export const initializeFirebase = () =>{
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission().then(()=>{
        return messaging.getToken()
    }).then(token=>{
        console.log('Token : ',token);
        localStorage.setItem('FIREBASE TOKEN : ',token);
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log("FIREBASE ERROR : ",err);
    })
}
```

in my local using yarn watch the token is set in LocalStorage but in server the token in not stored.So that means in server yarn build the code is not triggered to `localStorage.setItem('FIREBASE TOKEN : ',token);`
What is the reason for this.please help

Comment: did you create in the public folder firebase-messaging-sw.js and provide your application config right there?

Comment: yes this is a magento pwa project in reactjs I have created the  firebase-messaging-sw.js in root folder

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. The problem is that the firebase-messaging-sw.js should be inside the dist folder.